# поле вода в Android приложение с всплывающей клавиатурой для ввода чисел в шестнадцатеричной системе счисления

Tags: android, android-studio, android-edittext, мобильная-разработка, мобильные-приложения

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть необходимость чтобы при нажатии на поле ввода в Android приложение перед пользователем всплывала клавиатура только с символами для вода числа в шестнадцатеричной системе счисления. Я как понимаю в android studio для EditText нельзя указать через "android:inputType" требуемый тип всплывающей клавиатуры, тогда есть ли сторонние библиотеки или прийдётся самому программировать клавиатуру?

Comment: http://mobile.antonio081014.com/2012/04/how-to-let-input-of-edittext-only-be.html